# How to convert htaccess rules to web.config for IIS7/Symfony?

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite, iis-7, web-config

I have a symfony2 project developed on a linux server and have migrated it (unfortunately!) to a windows server for reasons outside of my control. This all works as it should except for the url rewriting. I tried using the IIS URL Rewrite Module but it failed when converting most of the rules (and stupidly i didn't save a list of which ones it failed on).

It mostly works fine but the app.php is still present at the start of all urls which it shouldn't be. So the urls are domain.com/app.php/correct/path when they should be domain.com/correct/path

Unfortunately i rarely use windows servers and am not good at the web.config syntax so if anyone could suggest what is missing to remove the app.php from the start of all urls on the windows server then that would be greatly appreciated!

The original .htaccess file is:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

The converted web.config file is currently:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".?" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thanks very much!

Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have just had this same issue while setting up symfony2 on a Windows server using IIS7.5.
 The trick is to go into you web site management section. Look for 'url rewrite', look for 'Import Rules'(somewhere on the right). Then on the new dialogue browse for your .htaccess file in 'SymfonyProject/web/' by default. IIS will throw an error for the trailing slash rule so delete that (Everything seems to work fine without it) and press apply. Viola no app.php.

Be sure to add app.php to your list of default pages also.

I did the above using the standard htaccess file shipped with Symfony2.

## EDIT As Requested Below

In the Import Dialog I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /   <-This line needs deleting as IIS states "This directive was not converted because it is not supported by IIS: RewriteBase "
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

So the begining of my web.config looks like this:

```
<defaultDocument enabled="true">
    <files>
        <add value="app.php" />
    </files>
</defaultDocument>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="app.php" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Also I have set my web directory as my root directory.

Hope this helps.
Doug.

Comment: Thanks for the answer doug, much appreciated although this is exactly what I did as well but it did not convert all the rules for some reason. Would it be possible for you to post the resulting web.config file in your answer so I can see the specific rules, it would be massively helpful! Thanks :)

Comment: You're a legend, thanks Doug that solved it. Now that i look at it the missing elements are quite obvious, thanks for enlightening me!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but today i had the same problem and i searched everywhere  and took me a lot of time to fix it by replace the .htaccess file in web directory to web.config file with this content hope this will help some one .

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <defaultDocument>
                <files>
                    <clear />
                    <add value="app.php" />
                </files>
            </defaultDocument>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="Symfony Front Controller" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="app.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on a Plesk Linux to Plesk Windows migration. I removed the htaccess file and edited the default web.config file according to previous comments.

In my case, I just needed to change the "app.php" with "index.php" and then it works. This is the content of my web.config file

Hope it will helps !

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
          <rules>
              <rule name="Symfony Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                      </conditions>
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
              </rule>
          </rules>
      </rewrite>
    <tracing>
      <traceFailedRequests>
        <clear />
      </traceFailedRequests>
    </tracing>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```